# CTE with first three amounts per person

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I have a table with several money transfers per person:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Transactions](
    [sender] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [receiver] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [TranDate] [date] NULL,
    [amount] [money] NULL)
```

I have to write a query that returns a list of accounts that received lets say 1500 USD in three transactions. An account name should be listed if there are three (or fewer) transfers with the total of 1500 USD.
My query is the following:

```
    select d.receiver, d.Somme
    from(
    select a.receiver,sum(a.amount) as Somme 
    from (SELECT top 3 receiver,[amount]
    FROM [DEV_KPIGov].[dbo].[Transactions] 
    where receiver='Williams'
    order by [amount] DESC) a
    group by a.receiver
    union all
    select b.receiver,sum(b.amount) as Somme
    from (SELECT top 3 receiver,[amount]
   FROM [DEV_KPIGov].[dbo].[Transactions] 
   where receiver='Taylor'
   order by [amount] DESC) b
   group by b.receiver
   union all
   select c.receiver,sum(c.amount) as Somme
   from (SELECT top 3 receiver,[amount]
   FROM [DEV_KPIGov].[dbo].[Transactions] 
   where receiver='Jhonson'
   order by [amount] DESC) c
   group by c.receiver) d
   where d.Somme>=1500
```

Is there a more dynamic way to achieve this? I don't like the fact that I have to list every receiver's name in the "where" clause. I was wondering if it's possible via a CTE? I'm using SQL Server 2012. Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be possible with a window aggregate function :

```
select a.receiver, sum( a.amount) as amt
from( 
select receiver,[amount], 
row_number() over( partition by receiver order by amount desc) as rownum 
from [DEV_KPIGov].[dbo].[Transactions] 
) as a 
where rownum <= 3
group by a.receiver
having amt >= 1500
```

Comment: Happy to help!  if you're happy with my answer I'd love it if you accepted it using the green tick